# How to implement Auto Save plugin of Ck Editor 5 in nextjs?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have implement ck editor using custom build(following the documentation) but i am facing difficulty in implementing ***AutoSave*** plugin provided by ckeditor..currently i am using a handleChange function which somehow whenever called, losses the focus of the editor cursor and i have to again click in the editor to get the focus.

This handleChange function has 2 problems:

1. sometimes even if the image hasnt been uploaded yet, it runs and the image is neversaved.
2. it loses the focus of the cursor from the editor.

and on reading the documentation, i came to know that the solution to these problems is to implement the autosave plugin but i am not able to do that.

here is the link to the documentation:[text](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/autosave.html)

Here is  the code of the component:

```
// components/custom-editor.js

import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import Editor from "ckeditor5-custom-build";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useSeoContext } from "../lib/SEO_Context";

const editorConfiguration = {
  toolbar: [
    "heading",
    "|",
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "link",
    "bulletedList",
    "numberedList",
    "|",
    "outdent",
    "indent",
    "|",
    "imageUpload",
    "blockQuote",
    "insertTable",
    "mediaEmbed",
    "undo",
    "redo",
  ],
};

function CustomEditor(props) {
  const router = useRouter();

  let doc = router.asPath.split("=")[1];

  const {
    text,
    setText,
    handleUpdate,
  } = useSeoContext();

  let debounceTimeout = null;

  const handleChange = (html) => {
    clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
    debounceTimeout = setTimeout(async () => {
      setText(html);
      await handleUpdate(html, doc.slice(0, 24));
    }, 5000);
  };

  function uploadAdapter(loader) {
    return {
      upload: () => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
          const body = new FormData();
          loader.file.then((file) => {
            console.log(file);
            body.append("file", file);
            body.append("upload_preset", ".......");
            axios
              .post(
                "https://api.cloudinary.com/..........",
                body
              )
              .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
                const { secure_url } = response.data;
                resolve({ default: secure_url });
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
              });
          });
        });
      },
    };
  }

  function uploadPlugin(editor) {
    editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = (loader) => {
      return uploadAdapter(loader);
    };
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "94vh", overflow: "auto" }}>
      <CKEditor
        editor={Editor}
        config={{
          editorConfiguration,
          extraPlugins: [uploadPlugin],
        }}
        data={text}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const data = editor.getData();
          console.log(data);
          console.log({ event, editor, data });
          handleChange(data); // Call the provided onChange function
        }}
        onReady={(editor) => {
          editor.editing.view.change((writer) => {
            writer.setStyle(
              "height",
              "80vh",
              editor.editing.view.document.getRoot()
            );
          });
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomEditor;
```

I am using Page router of nextjs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEb1J.png)

I have explained everything above...